# Way around Extending Controller in symfony2.8 - containerAware deprecated

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine

I'm trying to create a simple login. I created my Entity and had the form displaying on the page. This is the link I followed: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

### Error

This is the error I get when I hit the controller:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

After a bit of research and digging I discovered that because I am extending to the symfony controller that then in turn extends ContainerAware. I'm guessing that this is the issue?

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Security;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:Loginpage:index.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}

public function loginCheckAction()
{
    //no logic needed
}
}
```

### Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
    <service id="controller.site.loginpage" class="AppBundle\Controller\Security\SecurityController">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <argument type="service" id="templating"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

### Routing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing  http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

<route id="loginpage" path="/login">
    <default key="_controller">
        controller.site.loginpage:loginAction
    </default>
</route>
```

Comment: can you put the line number of the error

Comment: Are you defining the controller as a service?  If so then you need to use setContainer in your service definition.

Comment: in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 391

Comment: Show us the route to controller, as @Cerad said, it's really possible that you call controller via service, that's why you haven't container injected.

Comment: Ahhhh okay ill add it in above -  i am using my controller as a service, wasnt aware that i had to inject the container tho, not entirely sure how its done, is it an argument on the service?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this is all new to me :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the createController() method in Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver.

It will give you a quick idea how your controller is initialized/returned. If you defined it as a service, the setContainer() method will not be called and get() method will be called on a non-object (null).

When you define controller as a service, you usually do NOT want to inject the whole container, but only specific services.

If you are just beginning to use Symfony2 (like I assume), I would suggest not defining it as a service, so you can keep things simple.

Comment: Add calls: [[setContainer, ['@service_container']]] to your service definition to inject the controller.  I disagree that with the statement they you would not normally inject the whole container.  But that is a different discussion.

Comment: I hope my answer helped. I studied a lot about controllers in Symfony. Yes, there is a lot to discuss about injecting container, and I agree, it's a different topic... and like I said "usually". :)